Opening and reading files from HTTP links in Notepad++ or other tool
I have many txt files which are stored on a web server and are changing very often (every second). Something like log files and tail.
I am able to open them in a browser, but I would prefer to open them in some other tool which has more features to read and analyze the files (also adding some colors, backgrounds for search phrases etc.).
Ideally it would be like a Notepad++ which can just show me the file. For instance it could look like this:

Is there any tool which has this function?

Following advices from answers and comments I have created my own powershell script, which

Gets contents from URL every 30 seconds
Gets only specific amount of data using "Range" HTTP request header.
Adds very basic color formatting for specific keywords

$green = [char]27 + "[32m"
$blue = [char]27 + "[34m"
$reset = [char]27 + "[0m"

$debugRegex = "\bplugins\b"
$infoRegex = "\bbuild\b"


while ($true) {
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fascynacja/blog-demos/master/gwt-marquee/pom.xml")
    $request.AddRange(-2000)
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
    $content = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $response.Close()

    $coloredLine = $content -replace $debugRegex, "$green`$&$reset" -replace $infoRegex, "$blue`$&$reset"

    Write-Output $coloredLine
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}

Script can be adjusted to change the Seconds, Range or they keywords to be coloured.
I used dummy link just to present how it works, in real live you might want to colour the debug levels like "INFO", "DEBUG" or search keywords.


I wrote my own log viewer (loxx) and it supports opening of http-files (or ftp / sftp) and supports also periodic updates (and many features around log files).
It is for Windows only -- so I hope it matches your reqs.
You can have a try here: loxx download and say then "File -> Open from URL".
Any feedback is welcome!

You could use something like Url Tail if you don't mind CLI. This is basically tail for HTTP files, which redownloads only changed bytes. Then you can filter specific phrases with e.g. grep or highlight them with colorizer like grc.
But if you want it only for GitHub or git in general, it's likely better to just use git and autofetch + autorefresh files.

It is in fact for log files stored on server, they are exposed via mapped http pages. I think your solution is what I would like to see but preferably in a GUI tool which I can install on Windows.

I don't think there's any GUI but good luck
